# Why there is no Path constructor in java.nio.files.Path?

Tags: java, io, path

The Path class has no documented constructor, but one creates instances via. `Paths.get( "...." )` which is a shorthand for `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( "..." )`. So can someone explain this design decission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can someone explain this design decision?

It is because JSR 203 allows paths to be issued from more than one [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html), unlike `File`, which is always linked to the file system the JVM lives on. In JSR 203, this filesystem is called the *default filesystem*. You can get a reference to it using [`FileSystems.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getDefault--).

You use [`Paths.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) to get a path from the default filesystem, which is strictly equivalent to `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()`. If you were to get a `Path` from another file system, you would use this particular file system's [`.getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).

As a proof that a `FileSystem` can be for (nearly) anything, here are a few implementations over different sources:

- [in memory](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem);
- [FTP](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-ftp);
- [SMB/CIFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcifsfilesystem/);
- [Dropbox](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-dropbox).

And there are a few others.