# Instantiating and Initializing java.nio.files.Path?

Tags: java, oop, code-organization

I would like to use java.nio.files.Path in a class I'm creating called "DocumentGenerator" but I'm not sure how to instantiate and initialize it when using a constructor that does not pass in another Path object. Here are my class variables and two constructors:

```
private ArrayList<String> totalOutput;
private ArrayList<String> programInput;
private Scanner in;
private String savePath, fileName;
private Path file;

public DocumentGenerator(Path file) {
    this.programInput = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.totalOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.in = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.file = file;
    this.savePath = "";
    this.fileName = "";
}

public DocumentGenerator(String savePath, String fileName) {
    this.programInput = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.totalOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.in = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.savePath = savePath;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.file = 
}
```

In the second constructor, savePath and fileName need some manipulation before I put them in my Paths object so I do not want to pass them into it just yet. Instead, I would like to try instantiating and initializing "file" to keep in line with good programming practice. My issue is that according to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040971/why-there-is-no-path-constructor-in-java-nio-files-path/28041229#28041229), Path has no constructor. What would be good programming practice in a case like this? *Can* it be instantiated and initialized in my constructor without a given path?

My question is *not* "How do I use java.nio.files.Path?", I can find that from the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit :
You don't have to instantiate every attributes of your object within your constructors, if you don't instantiate them they will be equal to null.

To create a new nio Path object :

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Path p = Paths.get("/tmp/myfile");
```

Comment: You want to create a Path instance from a String ? Path has no constructors because it's an interface, the implementation will be different for each file system. So you should have this.file = Paths.get(filename);

Comment: No simply use :  this.file = Paths.get(filename);

Comment: Ok I guess I understand now, what to do with this object if I have nothing for it in the constructor ? Then keep it null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107295/discussion-between-hobopowers-and-benoit-vanalderweireldt).